# RSpec, Capybara correct formatting

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara

Could someone tell me if the formatting of the following _spec test file is correct?  I'm going through the Rails 3 In Action tutorial and the book gives the following _spec test file but when I run the test it tells me the method `sign_in_as!` is undefined.  I'm not sure what the problem is as the method has worked in all previous test files.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Admin::UsersController do
  let(:user) { Factory(:confirmed_user) }

  context "standard users" do
    before { sign_in_as!(user) }

    it "are not able to access the index action" do
      get 'index'
      response.should redirect_to('/')
      flash[:alert].should eql("You must be an admin to do that.")
    end
  end
end
```

The error I get is this:

```
Failure/Error: before { sign_in_as!(user) }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `sign_in_as!'
```

Comment: where is `sign_in_as!` defined?

Comment: `sign_in_as!` is defined in spec/support/authentication_helpers.rb

Comment: is it included in controller specs?

Comment: ok, you know what, it turns out that `sign_in` needs to be used here instead of `sign_in_as!`.  I misread the directions.  And `sign_in` is defined inside `Devise::TestHelpers`.  So I must `include Devise::TestHelpers` inside the _spec test file...but I appreciate your help.